# MkMapView don't respond on touch event when panning and zooming?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have view controller that has mkMapview, buttons and another UiView on top of the Map. The map don't respond on touches event.
How can I make mapView to respond on touch events.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view
```

or disable userInteraction on your UIView

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
yourView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: It is enabled. UiView respond to touch events but Mapview don't respond because is underneath the view.